# Multiply values in a Collection

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, multiplication

Hi all I have something like this and i want to multiply each object's "number". for example 2(first object number)x3(second object number)=6 (answer should be 6) does anyone know how to do it? The array is not always same.here it has 2 objects but it can be changed.

```
[{"id":7,"date":"2020-03-14","number":2},{"id":20,"date":"2020-03-15","number":3}]
```

Updated answer(Working)

```
                     foreach ($studentDetail as $student){
                     $number = calendar::where('student_id','=',$student['id'])
                            ->where('date','>=',$jsonData->checkin)
                            ->where('date','<',$jsonData->checkout)
                            ->get();
                        Log::info($number );
                        $multiplied= $number ->reduce(function ($carry, $item) {
                             return $carry * $item->number;
                        }, 1);
                        Log::info($multiplied);
                        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `reduce()` method of `Laravel collection`

> The reduce method reduces the collection to a single value, passing
>   the result of each iteration into the subsequent iteration

```
$multiplied= $collection->reduce(function ($carry, $item) {
  return $carry * $item->number;
}, 1);
```

Comment: i want multiply each objects number.. for example first  object number x  second object number ?

Comment: i hope you understand my question. first object number = 2 , second object number is 3 , i want to multiply them not like `$item->number * 3` this

Comment: hey my bad its working !your code is working!!!!!!!! thanks a lot.

Comment: Glad to help!  Keep learning. and Don't forget to upvote the answer. :)

Comment: I am really sorry i can not upvote your answer because i have only 13 reputation. need 15 reputation to upvote .once i get i will sure do it. thanks a bunch !!!!

Comment: hi i need another help . `array (
  0 => 2,
  1 => 4,
  2 => 5,
)   if i have array like this`can i use your same code for it ?

Comment: if i want to multiply 2x4x5 elements how can i change your code?

Comment: yes can use `array_reduce` for array...https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php